# Calling Parent Document Function From Fancybox Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fancybox-2

I have a function in parent window called `getPage(id, page)`.
When I open `fancybox` window a `google map` is displayed.

I want to call `getPage(` when a user clicks on one of the markers. but I keep getting the following error - **undefined is not a function**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            console.log($(parent.document).find('#paramzMore').val()); // This works fine!
            $(this).getPage('92850','test.php'); // Here I get the error
    });
```

This is a function definition in the parent(from where fancybox is called) window

```
$.fn.getPage=function(id, page) {   
    //do something
}
```

What could be the problem that function `getPage` is undefined?

Comment: How exactly do you implement the map in the fancybox? Is it another document/page dat has been loaded into the fancybox or is it a map created in the parent page?

Comment: The map is created in the page that is opened by fancybox

Comment: then you must define `$.fn.getPage`  also in this page(which creates the map) and not in the parent page.